# first @Html.TextBoxFor field doesn't update model when doing an ajax post

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

Bit of a strange one this - within a form, I have some fields

```
 <div class="container">

              @*  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Reference)</div>
                </div>*@


                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="col-md-1" >@Html.Label("Amount:")</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" >@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" >@Html.Label("Includes VAT:")</div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" >@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IncludesVAT) </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and I post the data to a controller using:

```
function refreshData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDebitModel", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify($("#DebitForm").serialize())
    });
}
```

It all works but the first @Html.TextBoxFor or CheckBoxFor never passes its value to the controller (e.g. Amount in this case, but if I switch the order above so the checkbox is the first control then the checkbox value is always ignored).

I can get around it by having a hidden field - i.e. if I uncomment the above hidden field everything works. (It doesn't have to be a hidden for, it could be a TextBoxFor - and it doesn't matter which field in the model is referenced)

I am perplexed, I must be missing something here.  As I said I can make it work but I really want to understand why the first control (and only the first control) is ignored?

I'm calling the refreshData function on change:

```
$('#Amount').change(function () {
        refreshData();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the JSON.stringify from your code.  I have experienced this before and all the request parameters will be wrapped with quotes "Amount=x&IncludesVAT=y" therefore, the method gets confused about its parameters. If you remove the stringify, it will parse the data correctly.